# my sql :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Tags: php, mysql

i have query like this

```
select c.*,j.pict
from mst020 a
inner join mst022 c on c.mst020_id = a.id
    left join (select e.pict as pict from mst021 e 
where e.line_number = 
     (select max(f.line_number) from mst021 f where f.mst020_id = a.id)
     and e.mst020_id = a.id) j
```

but when i process this query,, error show :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

i'm trying to learn my sql because at oracle its not problme if g have subquery like that.thx

Comment: derived tables MUST haave a alias : (select e.pict as pict from mst021 e where e.line_number 
= (select max(f.line_number) from mst021 f where f.mst020_id = a.id) **AS tmp**

Comment: you need to use a table after `left join`

Comment: hmm i have tried but still error..

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `ON` statement to go with the rest of the `join`.
I've reformatted your query:

```
select c.*,j.pict
from mst020 a
inner join mst022 c on c.mst020_id = a.id
left join (
                SELECT e.pict as pict 
                FROM mst021 e 
                WHERE e.line_number = 
                                (
                                        SELECT max(f.line_number) 
                                        FROM mst021 f 
                                        WHERE f.mst020_id = a.id
                                )
                    AND e.mst020_id = a.id
          ) j
```

As you see, the last `left join` doesn't have an `on` clause, and the last `and` is misplaced. Also, in your inner most query (select max) you refer to the outermost query. This is not possible. You should probably rewrite the query, at least, I don't know what you are trying to do, so I can't correct it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show corrected query and error message

Answer (score 0):

i have an answer. the error because i'm join the table at sub query and with outside subquery like this

```
select c.*,j.pict
from mst020 a
inner join mst022 c on c.mst020_id = a.id
    left join (select e.pict as pict from mst021 e 
where e.line_number = 
     (select max(f.line_number) from mst021 f where f.mst020_id = a.id)
     and **e.mst020_id = a.id**) j on j.mst021_id = a.id
```

so i change to this and thats successful

```
select c.*,j.pict
from mst020 a
inner join mst022 c on c.mst020_id = a.id
    left join (select e.pict as pict from mst021 e 
where e.line_number = 
     (select max(f.line_number),g.mst021_id from mst021 f )) j on j.mst021_id = a.id
```

at my sql we can't join with table at outside subquery